# Setting the JAVA_HOME environment variable in Ubuntu

Tags: java, ubuntu, java-home

I'm pretty new on ubuntu, at some point in the terminal I'm running:

```
mortar local:illustrate pigscripts/retail-recsys.pig purchase_input -f params/retail.params
```

but I have this following error:

> A suitable java installation could not be found.  If you already have java installed
>   please set your JAVA_HOME environment variable before continuing.  Otherwise, a
>   suitable java installation will need to be added to your local system.
>
> Installing Java
>
> On OSX run `javac` from the command line.  This will intiate the installation.  For
>   Linux systems please consult the documentation on your relevant package manager.

But I'm pretty sure I have Java, so please how can I set my JAVA_HOME environment variable?

Comment: I did some mousing around, and [I found this document page](http://help.mortardata.com/data_apps/recommendation_engine/install_mortar) related to Mortar.  I'm willing to bet that's what you want to use to export your JAVA_HOME when you're running/installing it.

Answer (score 20):

First, you need to decide which installed version of Java to use? No fear, you can pick any you have -

```
update-java-alternatives -l
```

One "easy" solution is to add this to "$HOME/.bashrc",

```
export JAVA_HOME=$(update-java-alternatives -l | head -n 1 | awk -F ' ' '{print $NF}')
```

This picks the first installed JDK and takes it's JAVA_HOME (the third field) - on my system that's

```
/usr/lib/jvm/java-1.7.0-openjdk-amd64
```

Comment: this is only a temporary solution, and will get cleared upon reboot.

Comment: @IgorGanapolsky No, if you add it to ".bashrc" it will not.

Comment: On Ubuntu 14.04, a symlink /usr/lib/jvm/default-java was created when I installed jdk via apt. I used this for the JAVA_HOME environment variable.

Comment: I needed to update this solution for Ubuntu 16.4 to take out the multiple spaces between the  3 parts. So I use `export JAVA_HOME=$(update-java-alternatives -l | head -n 1 | sed 's/  */ /g' | cut -f3 -d' ')`

Answer (score 6):

```
export JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/java-7-oracle
```

in your `~/.bashrc` file.

If you want this environment variable available to all users and on system start then you can add the following to /etc/profile.d/java.sh (create it if necessary):

```
export JDK_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/java-7-oracle
export JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/java-7-oracle
```

Then in a terminal run:

```
sudo chmod +x /etc/profile.d/java.sh
source /etc/profile.d/java.sh
```

Answer (score 2):

The simplest method to set environment variable is with export:

```
    $ export JAVA_HOME="/usr/bin"
```

This will temporarily set the desired variable. You can check if it was set with:

```
    $ echo $JAVA_HOME
```

or

```
    $ printenv
```

If you want a more permanent solution, append 'export JAVA_HOME="/usr/bin"' to .bashrc or .bash_profile file.

To check if java is properly installed:

```
    $ which java
    $ which javac
```

You should get similar output:

```
    /usr/bin/java
```

Comment: Why /usr/bin/java?  What if I download jdk from Oracle into another directory?

Comment: Well, that was just a specific example :)

Comment: This is the best answer if you plan to use multiple versions of java. This allows you to use update-alternatives to set your java version, and it will work throughout.

Comment: It should be `export JAVA_HOME=/usr`, otherwise the system will look for the java executable in `/usr/bin/bin`.

Answer (score 2):

For `JAVA_HOME` to point to the active jdk, add to your `~/.bashrc`

```
export JAVA_HOME=$(update-alternatives --query javac | sed -n -e 's/Best: *\(.*\)\/bin\/javac/\1/p')
```

which will dynamically set the `$JAVA_HOME` to the JDK selected by `update-alternatives`.

Comment: Thank you so much this is the best answer :)

Comment: In order to get the currently configured alternative, I think it should be: `update-alternatives --query javac | sed -n -e 's/Value: *\(.*\)\/bin\/javac/\1/p'`

Answer (score 1):

put the line `export JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/java-xxx-oracle` in your .profile file at home directory. Note that you have to replace xxx. You may need to logout and login again

Answer (score 1):

In Debian/Ubuntu/Linux Mint, we could add to .bashrc
export JAVA_HOME=$(update-java-alternatives -l | head -n 1 | sed 's/\s//g')

Answer (score 0):

Normally you can set paths in

~/.bashrc

with export JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/java-version

However you may followe instructions from [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/55848/how-do-i-install-oracle-java-jdk-7) for a comprehensive instruction.

Comment: I set it in .bashrc, but do I have to reboot??  It doesn't take effect.

Answer (score -1):

By far, [the ultimate guide to doing this is here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/56104/how-can-i-install-sun-oracles-proprietary-java-jdk-6-7-8-or-jre).  You don't need to set PATH as much as you just need to adjust the default 'java alternative' location.

Answer (score -1):

you can  type java in terminal,if it does not work means your did not install java.if it works, type javac in terminal.if javac dose not work,you should set the java environment variable,if it works ,there maybe something wrong with you program.