# Elasticsearch Failed to start service in Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: elasticsearch, ubuntu-20.04

(I am new to elastic search)

I want to start the elastic search as a service (sudo systemctl start elasticsearch), but it won't start, and throw an error as given below in the image
[image]

So after that, I went through to log file of elasticsearch log at `/var/log/elasticsearch/my-application.log`there I found some issues which is out of my range, The files attached below for error log is

https://filebin.net/ca3a5l67t2hqcexd

The piece of code I have tried so far

```
sudo apt-cache search openjdk
sudo apt-get install openjdk-11-jre openjdk-11-jdk
java -version (openjdk 14.0.1 2020-04-14 OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 14.0.1+7-Ubuntu-1ubuntu1) OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 14.0.1+7-Ubuntu-1ubuntu1, mixed mode, sharing))
sudo gedit /etc/environment
JAVA_HOME="/usr/lib/jvm/java-14-openjdk-amd64"
echo $JAVA_HOME (/usr/lib/jvm/java-14-openjdk-amd64)
curl -fsSL https://artifacts.elastic.co/GPG-KEY-elasticsearch | sudo apt-key add - (OK)
echo "deb https://artifacts.elastic.co/packages/7.x/apt stable main" | sudo tee /etc/apt/sources.list.d/elastic-7.x.list  - (deb https://artifacts.elastic.co/packages/7.x/apt stable main)
sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get install elasticsearch
sudo gedit /etc/elasticsearch/elasticsearch.yml
overwritted in yml file of elasticsearch
(cluster.name: my-application
node.name: magentocom
network.publish.host: localhost
discovery.seed_hosts: []
network.host: 127.0.0.1
http.port: 9200
cluster.initial_master_nodes: 127.0.0.1)
sudo systemctl start elasticsearch
```

I have also given permission as per suggested answer but still no success:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/38539220/9427866

Any help will be appreciated!

Comment: What is error logs of Es?

Comment: sorry to bother, where can I find the logs for ES @ThanhNguyenVan

Comment: first of all you should share error part from my-application.log. second you set java_home as java version 14? and installed java version 11? although there is no need to install java because elasticsearch have embedded java 11.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just try to replace `network.publish.host` with `network.publish_host`

Comment: at what file this has to be done?

Answer (score 2):

As you are running your elasticsearch locally, I would suggest to keep the configs minimal and don't use the advance network settings like `network.publish_host` mentioned in [official network doc](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/modules-network.html).

As your error logs are filled with `network.publish_host`, I would suggest to remove  all the settings from your `elasticsearch.yml` and just keep below settings and restart ES.

```
discovery.type: single-node
http.port: 9200
```

Please refer my [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61547317/4039431) for more info on `single-node` and startup issues.

Answer (score 0):

Only for Virtual Machine users. (**Virtual box Ubuntu 20** I had the same issue)

Replaced

```
network.host: 192.168.0.1
```

with

```
network.host: 127.0.0.1
```

Also this (Optionally) without below also worked

```
discovery.type: single-node
```

Answer (score 0):

setting the following:
-Xms4g
-Xmx12g

In jvm.options worked for me. All security is enabled (to true) and able to login as well. In Ubuntu 22.04